# AngularJS - route with parameter to be accesses globally

Tags: angularjs, url, parameter-passing, ngroute

I am creating a survey form in AngularJS. The requirement is this that the survey link with surveyId in parameter will be provided in email.

I tired the following code, but I can't access the surveyId in the receiving controller, it shows undefined. Moreover when I try to access the url with parameter directly, it does not load.

This is how I am trying to access the link directly in my local environment, where 4 is the surveyId
http://localhost:9000/fillSurvey/4

Can someone please guide me in the right direction?`

```js
var app = angular.module('mainApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',


  function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    /*$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');*/

    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
      enabled: true,
      requireBase: false
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/fillSurvey/:surveyId', {
        templateUrl: 'surveyManagement/views/surveysList.html',
        controller: 'fillSurveyCtrl'
      })

      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      })

  }
]);


app.controller('fillSurveyCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$http', '$localStorage', '$filter', '$interval', function($scope, $location, $http, $localStorage, $filter, $interval, $routeParams) {


  $scope.surveyId = $routeParams.surveyId;
  alert($scope.surveyId);

}]);
```

**EDIT**

So I was missing to add dependency '$routeParams' that is why got undefined. 
Can someone please guide me how to make the link accessible from anywhere like this
baseURL/fillSurvey/5

where 5 is the survey id

Thanks

Comment: So accessing it via $routeParams.surveyId gives you nothing?

Comment: As far as i can see, you didn't import dependency **$routeParams** into controller.

Comment: it gives undefined! My major issue is to make the link accessible from the URL directly. For now I access it from clicking a button in another page and that is how it only works.

Comment: `app.controller('fillSurveyCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$http', '$localStorage', '$filter', '$interval', function($scope, $location, $http, $localStorage, $filter, $interval, $routeParams) {` - add `$routeParams` after `'$interval'`

Comment: @Aks1357 as i mentioned above

Comment: @VinkoVorih You are right mate! that made it work but how can i make it accessible like this from anywhere

http://localhost:9000/fillSurvey/4
baseURL/fillSurvey/4

Comment: if you want global scope then declare it as $rootScope and import dependency **$rootScope** into controller.

Comment: @VinkoVorih - yes, so upvoted your comment, didn't see your comment until I posted mine

Comment: @VinkoVorih declare what as $rootscope? Can you please provide more details

Comment: Stop using this ugly, error-prone array notation, and use ng-annotate to do it for you.

Comment: if you want access $scope.surveyId from outside of controller, you should declare it as $rootScope.surveyId and add dependency $rootScope into controller.

Comment: No this is not what mean!! I want the url to accessible when i hit it directly in the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your controller is not configured properly.

Compare 
['$scope', '$location', '$http', '$localStorage', '$filter', '$interval',

---

function($scope,     $location,  $http,   $localStorage,    $filter, $interval, **$routeParams**
)

I hope you figured it out.

Comment: Yes VinkoVorih pointed it. I fixed it and I get the survey id in controller. But my issue is I want the link to be accessible by just hitting the URL
e.g. http://localhost:9000/fillSurvey/4 should work from everywhere, obviously with correct baseURL and not localhost.

Comment: Any where you mean in you local network ? if yes Then find your ip address by ipconfig command. and use your ipaddress:9000/fillSurvey/4.  Note plz if it address your question then mark it as answer.

Comment: Yes, that is what I want.. I think the issue is that the template is a partial in angular.. and I have to load the resources in this particular view too.